# Microsoft Equivalent of WebkitGTK hovering-over-link signal

Tags: c++, browser, mshtml, iwebbrowser2

I need to add ability to catch event each time there is mouse hover event both on Linux and Windows. In Linux I easily connect to [hovering-over-link](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebFrame.html#WebKitWebFrame-hovering-over-link) signal. I cannot seem to find Windows equivalent. Searched google, checked the MSDN, I could not find.

Does Such a functionality available in windows? If no is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [StatusTextChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event? This event is fired when the mouse is hovered over a link, with `sText` set to the link URL.
It is also fired with additional messages such as when loading a page. In these cases, `sText` is set to "Connecting to (URL)", "Waiting for (URL)", etc. These messages can be simply ignored by doing a basic URL validation of `sText`.

A more involved method would be in the [DocumentComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event to search for all anchor elements using [getElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and attach to the [HTMLAnchorEvents onmouseover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This of course wouldn't work for anchor elements dynamically created after page load.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that! Now one more question, how do I do validation seeing that url may have a lot of formats (especially custom url within app like link://some/data/here/2/1)?